# Extra xmlns="" in web service XML being sent / Child element X does not belong in namespace

Tags: xml, web-services

I'm making a call to a customer's web service in a VS2010 VB.Net console app.  I did the usual right-click on project / add service reference / advanced button / add web reference, navigated to the URL, and added the reference.

The app is calling our customer’s web service to pass it data, so that they can update their database with it.  We’re using their WSDL, which hasn’t changed.

Their side is rejecting some of the transactions, oy.

The message on their end is that "Child element X does not belong in namespace", which made me think that X is not part of the wsdl, but I can open IE and navigate to it and see it.

Our customer thinks it's because of and extra xmlns="" showing up in a few nodes.  For other nodes, it doesn’t appear.
We don’t want it to be there and have a value, as I’ve seen various answers for on the web; we want it to not be there at all.

Here’s the format of the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<SYNC_V1_REQUEST xmlns="https://OurCustsWebserviceURL.com/types">
<ORDER xmlns="">
<ROW_ID>1234</ROW_ID>
```

...then the rest of the nodes for the ORDER , then the closing node for the order, etc.

For other types of data, e.g., a CUSTOMER row, there’s no such extra xmlns="".

Does anyone have any ideas how I get rid of it?

Thanks in advance, ladies & gentlemen!

Answer (score 0):

Same as post [Is xmlns="" a valid xml namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587891/is-xmlns-is-a-valid-xml-namespace)

http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting 
The attribute value in a default namespace declaration MAY be empty. This has the same effect, within the scope of the declaration, of there being no default namespace.